# Extract data from a Cell Array using a vector and converting into an array

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a cell array [5x1] which all cells are column vectors such as:

```
exInt =

    [46x1 double]
    [54x1 double]
    [40x1 double]
    [51x1 double]
    [ 9x1 double]
```

I need to have a vector (vec) containing the cells in extInt I need to extract and then I have to convert these into a single column array. Such as:

```
    vec = [1,3];
    Output = cell2mat(extInt{vec})
```

Output should become something an array [86x1 double].

The way I have coded I get:

```
Error using cell2mat
Too many input arguments.
```

If possible, I would like to have a solution not using a loop.

Comment: What's the question? Doesn't this code work? If not, please list why not.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've edited the question.

Comment: Try [`cellfun`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best approach here is to use [`cat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) along with a [comma-separted list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) created by `{}` indexing to yield the expected column vector. We specify the first dimension as the first argument since you have all column vectors and we want the output to also be a column vector.

```
out = cat(1, extInt{vec})
```

Given your input, `cell2mat` attempts to concatenate along the *second dimension* which will fail for your data since all of the data have different number of rows. This is why (in your example) you had to transpose the data prior to calling `cell2mat`.

**Update**

Here is a benchmark to compare execution times between the `cat` and `cell2mat` approaches.

```
function benchit()

    nRows = linspace(10, 1000, 100);

    [times1, times2] = deal(zeros(size(nRows)));

    for k = 1:numel(nRows)

        rows = nRows(k);

        data = arrayfun(@(x)rand(randi([10, 50], 1), 1), 1:rows, 'uni', 0);
        vec = 1:2:numel(data);

        times1(k) = timeit(@()cat_method(data, vec));

        data = arrayfun(@(x)rand(randi([10, 50], 1), 1), 1:rows, 'uni', 0);
        vec = 1:2:numel(data);

        times2(k) = timeit(@()cell2mat_method(data, vec));
    end

    figure

    hplot(1) = plot(nRows, times1 * 1000, 'DisplayName', 'cat');
    hold on
    hplot(2) = plot(nRows, times2 * 1000, 'DisplayName', 'cell2mat');

    ylabel('Execution Times (ms)')
    xlabel('# of Cell Array Elements')

    legend(hplot)
end

function out = cat_method(data, vec)
    out = cat(1, data{vec});
end

function out = cell2mat_method(data, vec)
    out = cell2mat(data(vec)');
end
```

[image]

The reason for the constant offset between the two is that `cell2mat` calls `cat` internally but adds some additional logic on top of it. If you just use `cat` directly, you circumvent that additional overhead.

Answer (score 3):

You have a small error in your code

Change

```
Output = cell2mat(extInt{vec});
```

to

```
Output = cell2mat(extInt(vec));
```

---

For cells, both brackets and parentheses can be used to get information. You can read some more about it [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/06/21/cell-arrays-and-their-contents/), but to summarize:

> - Use curly braces {} for setting or getting the contents of cell    arrays.
> - Use parentheses () for indexing into a cell array to collect    a subset of cells together in another cell array.

In your example, using brackets with index vector `vec` will produce 2 separate outputs (I've made a shorter version of `extInt` below)

```
extInt = {[1],[2 3],[4 5 6]};
extInt{vec}
ans =
     1
ans =
     4     5     6
```

As this is 2 separate outputs, it will also be 2 separate input to the function `cell2mat`. As this function only takes one input you get an error.

One alternative is in your own solution. Take the two outputs and place them inside a new (unnamed) cell

```
{extInt{vec}}
ans = 
    [1]    [1x3 double]
```

Now, this (single) result goes into `cell2mat` without a problem.
(Note though that you might need to transpose your result before depending on if you have column or row vectors in your cell. The size vector (or matrix) to combine need to match/align.)

Another way as to use parentheses (as above in my solution). Here a subset of the original cell is return. Therefore it goes directly into the `cell2mat`function.

```
extInt(vec)
ans = 
    [1]    [1x3 double]
```

Comment: this works too.I thought cell arrays could only use {}

Comment: @ArturCastiel `{}` returns the *contents* of the cell array elements and `()` returns a subset of the cell array as a cell array

Comment: Indeed, I'll update my answer with some more information

Answer (score 0):

I have been messing around and I got this working by converting this entry into a new cell array and transposing it so the dimensions remained equivalent for the concatenating process

```
Output = cell2mat({extInt{vec}}')
```

Comment: I have added a benchmark to my answer using `cat` instead of `cell2mat` to compare performance.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 Output = cell2mat(extInt(vec))
```

Since you want to address the cells in `extInt` not the content of the cells

```
extInt(vec)
extInt{vec}
```

try those to see whats going on

Comment: Why'd you give the same answer as [nilZ0r](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39348928/5211833) four minutes later? And that without any effort to explain why that is happening.

Comment: @Adriaan as you said it was **just 4 minutes.** That is a reasonably short time to expect overlap in answers. Why would you question someone for that?